# Pass Parameters in Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I had this query below and got an error with parameter @emp_group during execution. Need your suggestion on how to pass the parameter.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
    
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [LogDate], 106) + ']', 
                   '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [LogDate], 106) + ']')
                   FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT LogDate FROM AttendanceLog where LogDate between DateFrom and DateTo) PV  
                   ORDER BY [LogDate]
                   
    SET @query = '  SELECT * FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT * FROM Table1 A
                    INNER JOIN Table2 B ON B.empno= A.empno WHERE A.Status =  ''Active'' and B.EmployeeGroup = @emp_group
                        
                 ) PvTable
                 PIVOT 
                 (
                     SUM(OTHrs)
                     FOR [LogDate] IN (' + @cols + ')
                     
                ) PvTable      
                ';     
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

The query will run when removing the parameter but need to filter the records. thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: And where is this @emp_group coming from? What datatype it is? It is not declared anywhere in this query.

Comment: The parameter @emp_group was declared in the procedure but it was not shown in the above query. It was declared as nvarchar datatype. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can do the same thing with @emp_group like you did with @cols.
Extract them vom the text and pass them as a paramenter.

```
SET @query = 'SELECT * 
              FROM (SELECT A.*, B.EmployeeGroup
                    FROM Table1 A
                    INNER JOIN Table2 B ON B.empno= A.empno 
                    WHERE A.Status =  ''Active'' and B.EmployeeGroup = ''' + @emp_group + ''') PvTable
              PIVOT(SUM(OTHrs) FOR [LogDate] IN (' + @cols + ')) PvTable';
```

Comment: When I put a static value of @emp_group in the query for example, @emp_group=''Daily'' it did returns records. But when using as parameter, the problem occurs. Can you provide a sample on how to do that in the stored procedure? The stored procedure will accept 3 parameters (DateFrom, DateTo, EmployeeGroup)

Comment: i modified the sql statement. please take care that when you join Table1 with Table2 not to use "SELECT * FROM" ... that generates duplicate column names and sql server will not allow this. Please, specify the sql statement for your needed output.

Comment: Thank you Sir and it works! The actual query really select specific columns and not returing all columns on both tables.